# Explain the working of user defined wrapper with malloc

Tags: c, malloc, wrapper

Can someone explain me the working of a malloc wrapper for below code??

RTLD_NEXT should find the next syblo in search order, which means it should hit my malloc, where i haven't put any allocation scheme like original malloc.

Then how come the allocation is taking place?

I have done something like this in my code:

```
enter code here: tracer.cc
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static void* (*lt_malloc)(size_t size);
#define LT_MALLOC (*lt_malloc)

void *malloc(size_t sz)
{
    printf("My malloc called");
    return LT_MALLOC(sz);
}

int main()
{
    if (!lt_malloc)
    {
           lt_malloc = (void*(*)(size_t))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
        if (!lt_malloc)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "LeakTracer: could not resolve 'malloc' in 'libc.so': %s\n", dlerror());
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    int *p=(int*)malloc(10);
    *p=34;
    printf("Address of p: %u, value: %d\n",p,*p);

    p=(int*)malloc(10);
    *p=45;
    printf("Address of p: %u, value: %d\n",p,*p); */

}
```

Check the GDB output, nowhere it goes to libc malloc. Then from where is the memory allocation taking place?

```
enter code here
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804855d: file malloc1.c, line 25.

(gdb) s
The program is not being run.

(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/raj/timer_test/malloc_wrapper/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at malloc1.c:25
25       int *p=(int*)malloc(20);

(gdb) s
malloc (sz=20) at malloc1.c:10
10       printf("My malloc called");

(gdb) s
11       return LT_MALLOC(sz);

(gdb) s
12      }

(gdb) s
main () at malloc1.c:26
26       *p=45;

(gdb) s
27       printf("Address of p: %u, value: %d\n",p,*p); 

(gdb) s
My malloc calledAddress of p: 146501640, value: 45
29       p=(int*)malloc(20);

(gdb) s
malloc (sz=20) at malloc1.c:10
10       printf("My malloc called");

(gdb) s
11       return LT_MALLOC(sz);

(gdb) s
12      }

(gdb) s
main () at malloc1.c:30
30       *p=56;

(gdb) s
31       printf("Address of p: %u, value: %d\n",p,*p); 

(gdb) s
My malloc calledAddress of p: 146501664, value: 56
32      }

(gdb) s
0x006a8e9c in __libc_start_main () from /lib/libc.so.6

(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function __libc_start_main, 
which has no line number information.

Program exited with code 043.
(gdb)
```

My confusion, is in which step and how the libc original malloc is called? And why can't the GDB trace it?

**One more question, suppose after certain time (may be timer expiry) i want to call original malloc and not mine. How to do that?**

Comment: Why do you cast the return value of `malloc`? Especially when you're casting it to the wrong type?

Comment: Are you sure you have debug symbols for your libc installed? gdb usually won't step into a function if it doesn't have the source code for it installed. Have you tried stepping by assembly instruction from line 11?

Comment: @Chris: Where do you see i am casting to the wrong type? Everything is correct.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - `char *p = (int *)malloc(10);` should be yielding a few compiler complaints, if not flat out errors.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 instead of "s", step using "si"

Comment: @Chris: Ohhh you can ignore that, that was a typo. Will correct it :)

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - It's a totally unnecessary problem. `int *p = malloc(10)` is just as valid. (Also, `int *p = malloc(10)` is wrong unless `10 % sizeof(int) == 0`. You should use `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int))` or `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p)`, and if you need 10 of them, multiply by the size.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks, i know all these. But it is always better to typecast, because malloc returns pointer of void* type.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - There is no gained safety in explicitly casting a `void *` pointer compared to the implicit cast. The explicit cast just takes more work and can cause problems in the future.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Yes, that applies when one is a college level programmer, if you are in a software industry, there are some coding guidelines and rules that every engineer should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think that what is going on is that with the dlsym() call you are getting the address to the malloc in the libc, so your malloc function is acting as a wrapper around the libc malloc [but with the same name]
You say:

> "which means it should hit my malloc"

but are you sure the symbol for your malloc is the second one? ;) It might be it is the first one, as your malloc is in the same compilation unit.

Comment: @sergico: '''Probably''', you are correct. If i do thia: `p=(int*)LT_MALLOC(10);` the statement "My malloc called is not getting printed" But LT_MALLOC is return value from dlsym right? And specifying RTLD_NEXT in dlsym should point to our malloc. So how come it is hitting the default malloc using LT_MALLOC instead of lt_malloc?

Comment: @kingsmasher: The string `LT_MALLOC`is simply replaced with the string `lt_malloc`; and yes, the `lt_malloc` function pointer seems to receive from the dlsym() call the pointer to the libc malloc. If you are on a Unix-like system, try nm on the executable and grep for malloc, you might be able to see which one is first in the symbol table. Also, try replacing RTLD_NEXT with RTLD_DEFAULT, this might select the "other" malloc implementation [hopefully yours :)]

Comment: @sergico: `[root@raj malloc_wrapper]# nm a.out | grep malloc ``Output:080498b0 b lt_malloc 0804852c T malloc` T = defined in my code, what is this b?

Comment: @sergico: This after replacing, both mallocs with LT_MALLOC, with both as malloc( ) instead of LT_MALLOC the output is again the same as above

Comment: @kingsmaster: b mean: `The symbol is in the uninitialized data section (known as BSS)`  If you replace RTLD_NEXT with RTLD_DEFAULT does your malloc get selected?

Comment: @sergico: Yes, it does, and that is why it falls into an infinite loop. malloc, in return value again invokes malloc. But output of nm is same !!! One more doubt, i thought RTLD_NEXT should select tnhe "next" malloc after the default one(libc). Right? Please tell me, why this RTLD_NEXT and RTLD_DEFAULT are in confusion? Also why nm value everytime shows same?